# how to sort a collection with simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, collections, simple-form

I'm pulling a list of categories from a model.
In the admin section I want to use it to assign categories to products.
It's working fine but the list shows in the order the categories have been added.
I'd like to sort them alphabetically but I can't suss it out.

I'm sure it's pretty simple (hopefully)

here's my code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@game) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.input :copy %>
  <%= f.input :image %>
  <%= f.input :thumbnail %>
  <%= f.input :heroimage %>
  <%= f.association :category, collection: @categories %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I tried to add a `.sort_by(desc)` or just `.sort` on the collection method but it doesn't change the list.

Cheers

Comment: I have the same issue. Explicitly sorted collection but renders it in a random fashion. Actually, it sorts by `value_method`. In my case it's the `id` column.

Answer (score 8):

Here is how you should update your code:

```
<%= f.association :category, collection: Category.order('name ASC') %>
```

This assumes you want to sort by the category name, in ascending order.

Answer (score 4):

I imagine @categories is assigned as an arel in your controller, can you add an .order("description") to that; e.g.

```
@categories = Category.order('description')
```

Comment: As it's an association, can I have the collection sorting in the Category controller,or does it need to live in the Game controller. Where i have put it for now?

Comment: It would need to live in the controller that is rendering. but, sounds like perhaps you want this association ordered always? Does this help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127192/rails-order-by-in-associated-model

Comment: @categories = Category.order('description') works fine. I've implemeted active admin and now it's stopped working. Is it due to the admin namespace?

Comment: No idea... what does "it's stopped working" mean - just the order is off, or there's an error ?

Comment: hehehe sorry, it means it is not sorted anymore. but just when i'm in the active admin namespace.