# Use a scope by default on a Rails has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many

Let's say I have the following classes

```
class SolarSystem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :planets
end

class Planet < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :life_supporting, where('distance_from_sun > ?', 5).order('diameter ASC')
end
```

`Planet` has a scope `life_supporting` and `SolarSystem` `has_many :planets`. I would like to define my has_many relationship so that when I ask a `solar_system` for all associated `planets`, the `life_supporting` scope is automatically applied. Essentially, I would like `solar_system.planets == solar_system.planets.life_supporting`.

### Requirements

- I do **not** want to change `scope :life_supporting` in `Planet` to

  `default_scope where('distance_from_sun > ?', 5).order('diameter ASC')`
- I'd also like to prevent duplication by not having to add to `SolarSystem`

  `has_many :planets, :conditions => ['distance_from_sun > ?', 5], :order => 'diameter ASC'`

### Goal

I'd like to  have something like

`has_many :planets, :with_scope => :life_supporting`

## Edit: Work Arounds

As @phoet said, it may not be possible to achieve a default scope using ActiveRecord. However, I have found two potential work arounds. Both prevent duplication. The first one, while long, maintains obvious readability and transparency, and the second one is a helper type method who's output is explicit.

```
class SolarSystem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :planets, :conditions => Planet.life_supporting.where_values,
    :order => Planet.life_supporting.order_values
end

class Planet < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :life_supporting, where('distance_from_sun > ?', 5).order('diameter ASC')
end
```

Another solution which is a lot cleaner is to simply add the following method to `SolarSystem`

```
def life_supporting_planets
  planets.life_supporting
end
```

and to use `solar_system.life_supporting_planets` wherever you'd use `solar_system.planets`.

Neither answers the question so I just put them here as work arounds should anyone else encounter this situation.

Comment: your workaround using where_vales is really the best available solution and worth an accepted answer

Comment: `where_values` might not work with hash conditions: `{:cleared => false}` ... it gives an array of hashes that ActiveRecord doesn't like. As a hack, grabbing the first item in the array works: `Planet.life_supporting.where_values[0]`...

Comment: I found I had to use `where_ast` rather than `where_values` or `where_values_hash` as I had used AREL in the scope on the other model.  Worked a treat! +1

Answer (score 150, accepted):

In Rails 4, `Associations` have an optional `scope` parameter that accepts a lambda that is applied to the `Relation` (cf. the doc for [ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Customizing+the+query))

```rb
class SolarSystem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :planets, -> { life_supporting }
end

class Planet < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :life_supporting, -> { where('distance_from_sun > ?', 5).order('diameter ASC') }
end
```

In Rails 3, the `where_values` workaround can sometimes be improved by using `where_values_hash` that handles better scopes where conditions are defined by multiple `where` or by a hash (not the case here).

```rb
has_many :planets, conditions: Planet.life_supporting.where_values_hash
```

Comment: Could you detail the rails 3 solution? The rails 4 one is so clean!

Comment: Looks like this was wanted by enough people that it was added to Rails 4 :D

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger The "Edit: Work Arounds" part of the question describes it quite well. The improvement I suggest adresses the problem with hash conditions described by Nolan in the question comments.

Comment: @Aaron yes I think it really makes sense to me (eg. group members and group admins who are member with scope admin). @gregoire I actually made it work with `where_values_hash`. But I wish the Rails 4 solution could be imported into Rails 3. Anyway thanks!

Comment: For Rails 3, I take it should read ```has_many :planets, conditions: Planet.life_supporting.where_values_hash``` to enforce the scope. This is also golden for eager loading.

Comment: I found out the hard way that ```where_values_hash``` does not work with text **where** clauses, e.g. ```User.where(name: 'joe').where_values_hash``` will return the expected conditions' hash, whereas ```User.where('name = ?', 'Joe').where_values_hash``` will not. Therefore, the planets example will likely fail.

Comment: @nerfologist Thanks for pointing out the mistake in the last code example, I edited the answer. Your second comment makes sense, I think it's what I was alluding to in the last paragraph of the answer. Feel free to edit my answer if you can find a clearer way to explain the limitations.

Comment: @GrégoireClermont this is no more working in Rails 5

Answer (score 27):

In Rails 5, the following code works fine...

```
  class Order 
    scope :paid, -> { where status: %w[paid refunded] }
  end 

  class Store 
    has_many :paid_orders, -> { paid }, class_name: 'Order'
  end
```

Comment: AMAZING! `-> { paid }` is what I had tried so hard to make work. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

i just had a deep dive into ActiveRecord and it does not look like if this can be achieved with the current implementation of `has_many`. you can pass a block to `:conditions` but this is limited to returning a hash of conditions, not any kind of arel stuff.

a really simple and transparent way to achieve what you want (what i think you are trying to do) is to apply the scope at runtime:

```
  # foo.rb
  def bars
    super.baz
  end
```

this is far from what you are asking for, but it might just work ;)

Comment: Thanks phoet! This **will** work, however it will just look a bit odd in the code review. I think the feedback I'll get when implementing this is to instead do the duplication on the `has_many` declaration as it's clearer.

Comment: from my point of code-review i would prefer this option over duplication of conditions etc. as long as you provide a test for what it's meant to do, this approach is much more DRY and SRP

Comment: I highly recommend against using a method like this where an association would normally be used. I would instead remove the conditions from the association & a scope that is explicitly called on the association. It will be more maintainable and more clear in the future.

Comment: Oops, just realized this post was *really* old. Got here researching a similar issue.