# Rails: filter association based on current_user class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

Have an app where `current_user` can be a `Client` or and `Admin`. A `Client` can have many `Accounts` and an `AccountStatement` belongs to both the `Account` and the `Client`.

However there are some auto generated statements that we don't want to show the clients. I'd like to add a model scope of some kind that would look something like

```
    def account_statements
        if current_user.is_a?(Client)
            super.where(auto_generated: false)
        else
            super
        end
    end
```

so if I ran `.account_statements` on a valid instance of `Account` or `Client` it would only return a subset of the statements if the `current_user` is a `Client`, but all of them if the `current_user` is an `Admin`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just give each class its own method:

```rb
class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  def account_statements
    AccountStatement.all
  end
end

class Client < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  def account_statements
    AccountStatement.where(auto_generated: false)
  end
end
```

If you need `Client` to have a defined relationship to `AccountStatement`, things get a little more tricky:

```rb
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :account_statements

  # this method will supersede the relationship
  def account_statements
    ...
  end
end
```

In which case, you can either:

1. use a different name for the method
2. use [this cool relationship-with-scope trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19521603/1880203) to do something like this:

```rb
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :account_statements, -> { without_auto_generated }
end

class AccountStatement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :account

  scope :without_auto_generated, -> { where(auto_generated: false) }
end
```