# How do I sort on an association of a specific user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Profile` that can be `published`. A `profile` belongs_to `:user` and `has_many :ratings`.

A `User has_one :profile`, and `has_many :ratings`.

A `Rating belongs_to :profile && belongs_to :user`.

These are the schemas for the above models:

`Profile.rb`:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: profiles
#
#  id                      :integer          not null, primary key
#  first_name              :string
#  last_name               :string
#  created_at              :datetime         not null
#  updated_at              :datetime         not null
#  user_id                 :integer
```

`User.rb`:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  email                  :string           default(""), not null
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#  first_name             :string
#  last_name              :string
```

`Rating.rb`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: ratings
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  speed      :integer          default(0)
#  passing    :integer          default(0)
#  tackling   :integer          default(0)
#  dribbling  :integer          default(0)
#  profile_id :integer
#  user_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#
```

What I want to do is to find all the profiles, ranked by 1 `rating` attribute....e.g. all published profiles ranked by `passing` (highest to lowest).

I tried something like this:

```
Profile.published.where(id: coach.ratings.order(passing: :desc).pluck(:profile_id))
```

But that doesn't always give me the profiles in the order I expect.

So how do I do this query that allows me to get these profiles ranked by all of those ratings accordingly?

**Edit 1**

**Please Note** The key thing here is that I need to find the ratings on a profile left by a specific user.

In my query above, `coach = User.find(7)`.

So each `User` leaves a bunch of `ratings` on many `profiles`.

What I want to do is filter all the `profiles`, that have a specific rating (say `speed`) and order those profiles, by the speed rating from highest to lowest (but this is user specific).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. I see your logic seem conflic. Rating(profile_id, user_id). It means relationship User-Profile is n-n. But you set relationship profile-user is 1-1 before.

Comment: User-to-Profile is 1-1, Rating-to-Profile is n-n. How did you get User-Profile being n-n? The only that could be true is if I set a `has_many ratings_users through: :ratings`, no?

Comment: `User-Rating 1-n`, `Profile-Rating 1-n` => `User-Profile n-n`

Comment: Ahh interesting. So what's the solution you think? Isn't `User-Profile n-n` if only `thru Rating`?

Comment: I see `profiles` and `users` is the same. User has more only one field `email`. Could you use only 1 table `users` and remove table `profiles`?

Comment: Nope...they are two different things. Each user can have only 1 profile, but each user doesn't HAVE to have a profile and each profile doesn't HAVE to belong to a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a join:

```
Profile.published
  .joins(:ratings)
  .where(ratings: { user_id: coach.id } )
  .order('ratings.passing')
```

Comment: How do I find the ratings per the associated user? `coach` is a user in my original query. See the updated question to get more clarity on what I am looking for.

Comment: Bro....wow...perfect. That's exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm. So simple and clean. Can't believe I never thought about that `where(ratings:...)`.